# Optimizing in python over a function with an unknown variable

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to optimize a function in Python using *Brent's method*. The problem is we need to optimize over the following function: `Exp(max(x_i-y)) = c`, where y is supposed to be the output.
I tried the following but it gave me an error

```
def expectation(y, A, P):
    y = y.reshape((-1,1))
    subtraction = A-y
    result = (subtraction)%P
    max_result = np.maximum(result,0)
    exp_i=np.sum(max_result, axis=1)
    return exp_i

def eq_tau_c_i(A, P, c):
    equation = expectation(y, A, P) - c
    root = optimize.root_scalar(equation, method='brentq', bracket=[0, 2.0])
    solution = root.x
    return solution
```

Comment: which libraries are you using? Could you fix the imports?

Comment: what is the `max()` of a singleton?